# POWERBI, DAX : concatenate strings, split, and keep substrings only once

Tags: string, loops, powerbi, unique, dax

I try to do the following:

- I have a column with strings, each can have several substrings separated by a delimiter ":"
- I need to Concatenate the column strings (I do a Filter here to keep only interresting lines)
- Then split according to the delimiter ":"
- keep the substrings only once, if they are repeated.

Example:

```
ColumnHeader
AA:BB:CC
BB:DD
DD:AA:EE
EE:AA:DD:BB
BB:EE
...
```

Expected result would be a unique string:

```
"AA:BB:CC:DD:EE"
```

How would you do this in DAX to fill a new column ?

I expected to find for/while loops in DAX like in Python ... but failed.

I Tried this:

```
List =
VAR SIn = ""
VAR SOut = ""
VAR Cursor = 0
VAR SList =
        CONCATENATEX(
            FILTER(ATable, ATable[Name] = CTable[Name]),
            [ColumnHeader],
            ":")
VAR pos1 = FIND(":", SList, Cursor, len(SList))
VAR pos2 = FIND(":", SList, pos1, len(SList))
VAR elem = TRIM(MID(SList, pos1+1, pos2-pos1))

// following is not good but is what I would like to do:
VAR SOut = CONCATENATE(SOut, elem)
VAR SList = MID(SList, pos2, len(SList)-pos2)
VAR Cursor = pos2

// I need to loop ... but how ? ... as no for/while loops are possibles ?
```

Thanks for your help.

=====================================

I manage to tackle this thanks to the answers below.

I will still give a bigger data set for a better understanding of the global problem:

I have 2 tables:

```
TABLE_BY_ELEMENT            
KEY GROUP   LIST        KEY_DATA
1   G1      AA:BB:FF    11
2   G1      CC:AA       22
3   G1      FF:DD:AA    33
4   G1      CC:DD:AA    44
5   G2      CC:FF:GG    55
6   G2      BB:AA       66
            
            
TABLE_BY_GROUP          
GROUP   GROUP_DATA      
G1      1111        
G2      2222
```

And I want to view the data like this:

```
RESULT_BY_GROUP     
GROUP   GROUP_DATA  NewList
G1      111         AA:BB:FF:CC:DD
G2      222         CC:FF:GG:BB:AA
```

and also:

```
RESULT_ELEMENT      
KEY LIST        KEY_DATA
1   AA:BB:FF    11
2   CC:AA       22
3   FF:DD:AA    33
4   CC:DD:AA    44
5   CC:FF:GG    55
6   BB:AA       66
```

I hope is is easier to understand with this.

Comment: Might be best to do this in Power Query/M not DAX

Comment: For example you have 10 row, you wants 1 row/column with the final output? If not, please show your input and output exactly as what they are now and how you wants the final output.

Comment: I will try to split it in several lines. 1 line per value with the Query Editor...
The final result is that I want to view the values in a Card (or 1 line of a Table), according to the Slicer selection of the lines id (not shown in data sample) multiple selection allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't something DAX is suited for well. If you need to use DAX to make it into a dynamic measure, then you'll probably need to reshape your data to be more usable. For example,

```
ID   ColumnHeader
1    AA
1    BB
1    CC
2    BB
2    DD
3    DD
3    AA
3    EE
...
```

You can do this split in the query editor using the Split Column > By Delimiter tool and choosing to split on the colon and expand into rows.

[image: Split Column]

Once it's in this more usable format, you can work with it in DAX like this:

```
List = CONCATENATEX( VALUES('Table'[ColumnHeader]), 'Table'[ColumnHeader], ":" )
```

---

Borrowing logic from [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/DAX-how-split-a-string-by-delimiter-into-a-list-or-array/td-p/559597), it's *possible* to do this purely in DAX, but I don't recommend this route.

```
List =
VAR LongString =
    CONCATENATEX ( VALUES ( 'Table1'[ColumnHeader] ), Table1[ColumnHeader], ":" )
VAR StringToPath =
    SUBSTITUTE ( LongString, ":", "|" )
VAR PathToTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATESERIES ( 1, LEN ( StringToPath ) ),
        "Item", PATHITEM ( StringToPath, [Value] )
    )
VAR GroupItems =
    FILTER (
        SUMMARIZE ( PathToTable, [Item] ),
        NOT ISBLANK ( [Item] )
    )
RETURN
    CONCATENATEX ( GroupItems, [Item], ":" )
```

Comment: Hi Alexi,

Thanks, this seems an interesting solution.
I am testing this on a sample, and split the data in the query editor.

I see two problems now:
- it will make my table 4 times bigger:  about 4x15000 = 60000 lines. Is it ok ?
- I created the List as a new column, but I always have all the values of the whole list. The point is: if I filter only the odd Ids, the List will not update. How can I achieve this in my Visualization?  Thanks

Comment: 60k lines is perfectly fine. You need to make the List a measure, not a calculated column for it to be dynamic.

Comment: Ok, Great!! I'll try to do this with my full dataset tomorrow.
Just 2 last points to check:
...
1/ I will need to create an extra table just for this, so I do not break the unicity of my keys when splitting the data in columns (keys not shown in theexample). Is it correct ?
...
2/ I would like the calculated column to take into account the line context. How would you change the code to take a into account a "Group" column, and the concatenation should be done only with the lines within the same Group ?
Thx

Comment: Yes, you probably do need to create this as a new table with a one-to-many relationship from the original table ID to the new table ID. Writing this as a measure (*not* a calculated column) will allow it to calculate based on filter context. It should do this automatically in response to your filters, slicers, and context created by the visual you place it in.

Comment: Hi, Thank you! Hi, I did it this way, and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Let your table looks like below-

[image]

Now try this below **Advance Editor** code in the **Power Query Editor**-

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WcnS0cnKycnZWitWJVgKyXFzALBcXK6CMqyuY4+oK4gCFnJxgykAysQA=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [ColumnHeader = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ColumnHeader", type text}}),
    
    
    //--NEW STEPS STARTS FROM HERE
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Index",{"Index", "ColumnHeader"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Reordered Columns", "ColumnHeader", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"ColumnHeader.1", "ColumnHeader.2", "ColumnHeader.3", "ColumnHeader.4"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"ColumnHeader.1", type text}, {"ColumnHeader.2", type text}, {"ColumnHeader.3", type text}, {"ColumnHeader.4", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type1", {"Index"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute", "Index"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Columns"),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"Value", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Index1" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Reordered Columns1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Index1",{"Index", "Value"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns1", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Reordered Columns1", {{"Index", type text}}, "en-US")[Index]), "Index", "Value", List.Max),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Pivoted Column",{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged")
in
    #"Merged Columns"
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks fo this example. I notice I have more complex real life data. Is it possible to do the same if I have an extra column called "GROUP" and I want the concatenation to be done once for each Group. GROUP1 will have line 1 and 2, and GROUP2 line 3,4,5 ? The result would be like a two line table : GROUP1 AA:BB:CC:DD; and GROUP2 AA:BB:DD:EE. Is it possible to do this with Power Query ? Thanks.

Comment: Should I add a more detailed sample data here ? or should I post a new question ?

Comment: Possible... please provide more sample data for understanding.

Comment: Hi, I added a bigger set of data and results I need to find.
I am interrested in your way of doing it with PowerQuery, if you still think it is possible.
Thanks

Comment: Hi @Malo, check my another answer for your new case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code from **Power Query Editor** considering GROUP BY-

Create a new table **RESULT_BY_GROUP** with this below code-

```
let
    Source = TABLE_BY_ELEMENT,
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"KEY", "KEY_DATA"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "LIST", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"LIST.1", "LIST.2", "LIST.3"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"LIST.1", type text}, {"LIST.2", type text}, {"LIST.3", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"GROUP"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Columns1"),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Duplicates",{{"GROUP", Order.Ascending}, {"Value", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Sorted Rows", {"GROUP"}, {{"all", each _, type table [GROUP=nullable text, Value=text]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "NewList", each [all][Value]),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"NewList", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(List.Sort(_), Text.From), ":"), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"all"}),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Removed Columns2", {"GROUP"}, TABLE_BY_GROUP, {"GROUP"}, "TABLE_BY_GROUP", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded TABLE_BY_GROUP" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "TABLE_BY_GROUP", {"GROUP_DATA      "}, {"TABLE_BY_GROUP.GROUP_DATA      "}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Expanded TABLE_BY_GROUP",{{"TABLE_BY_GROUP.GROUP_DATA      ", "GROUP_DATA"}}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"GROUP", type text}, {"NewList", type text}, {"GROUP_DATA", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

Here is the final output-

[image]

You can easily visualize your second requirement for table **RESULT_ELEMENT** using your base table **TABLE_BY_ELEMENT**

Comment: I cannot copy paste the cod below : //--NEW STEPS STARTS FROM HERE
As I have error. Maybe my different version of POwerBi ?
Could you tell me a step by step process so I can reproduce it in the Power Query graphic editor ?

Comment: Where from you are getting //--NEW STEPS STARTS FROM HERE? New code do not contain this line. If you have table with exact name TABLE_BY_ELEMENT and TABLE_BY_GROUP and all column name as sample shown, its just a copy and paste of code should work.